# Run a Java class from Spring startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, war, wildfly

I am using Java8 and Spring4.3.1.

I have a Java/Spring application hosting RESTfult services accessed by browser and mobile app clients. Second, I have written a Chat Server that listens for events (`socket.io`) from the clients. This Chat Server is running from the classes `main` method.

The Chat Server class has a `main` method that I want to run, and allow to listen for events when my Spring application starts.  Is this possible?

If I run the `main` myself, it works, but I want it to start up when I start my Wildfly server that loads the Spring application.

Or is there a better approach?  Should the Chat Server not be running from the `main` method?

I have the following code:

```
package com.jobs.spring.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("rest", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dynamic.addMapping("/*");
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        try {
            com.jobs.spring.chat.Server chatServer = new com.jobs.spring.chat.Server();
            chatServer.run(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Server implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final String SERVER = "localhost";
    private static final Integer PORT = 3700;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        main(args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
...
```

and get the following error:

```
18:47:08,142 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbosswildfly: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbosswildfly: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/jobs/spring/chat/Server (Module "deployment.jbosswildfly.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/jobs/spring/chat/Server (Module "deployment.jbosswildfly.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner
```

Comment: It feels like you're mixing a whole bunch of different launcher patterns here. Is the intent of this server to be run over the Web? If not, why the servlet? If so, what's with the apparent "on the side" socket?

Comment: The Chat Server needs to run to listen to events. I Have an Ionic Mobile App that sends messages using sockets.io. If I run the Chat Server from the cmd line it works perfectly, but I have another Java Application running Spring with RESTful services. When this java app starts, I also want to start the chat server. Both the RESTful services and Chat Server need to be access from a browser and mobile app.

Comment: Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly, but I am here for advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy your chat server in `Wildfly`, by extending `SpringBootServletInitializer`, instead of launching it from a `main`.

Documentation: [howto-create-a-deployable-war-file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringBootApp.class);
    }

    //public static void main(String[] args){
    //    new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    //    .sources(SpringBootApp.class)
    //    .run(args);
    //}
}
```

Change the artifact produced to `war`, and deploy it normally in `wildfly`:

```
<project>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    ...
<project>
```

---

You may have to exclude tomcat, which is automatically imported with `spring-boot-starter-web`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Spring provided a Spring Boot example of a `pom.xml` for wildfly: [spring-boot-deployment-test-wildfly](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-deployment-tests/spring-boot-deployment-test-wildfly/pom.xml)

Comment: Alex, Is this a separate war from my exiting Java App?  Preferably I would want to run the chat server from the same application.  I try create the `SpringBootApp` class in my existing spring app and Spring Boot starts, but then get the following error: `StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./jbosswildfly: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer` and `New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:`

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I was just not sure, but now it's clear, it's a seperate app. I appreciate your help.