# How to run two spring boot application on a same jvm?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

The problem is what the title has described.

I have googled a lot.But the solution I found are a little old and not very useful for me.

I want to see the demo code and know the principle.

Any one can help? Really Thx.

Comment: Why are you needing to do that? Normally you'd either want to run them separately or just merge the context definitions.

Comment: My leader want me to try. He want to make the rpc system work in a same jvm so there would not  need so many time to transfer data on tcp.

Comment: Are you *replacing* the RPC "system" with a direct call between the apps? If not, then having the two apps running in different JVMs on the same machine will not be any slower than running them together, since you're still applying all the overhead of RPC and TCP loopback.

Comment: But, simplest way to run two independent apps in a single JVM is to set up two independent ClassLoaders.

Comment: Yes，my aim is replace the rpc with a direct call between the two app.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is downvoted. It's a reasonable question - can you run two Spring Boot applications in a single classloader, assuming no version discrepencies. For example does Spring use statics anywhere? In my test, running on separate ports worked but the dyamic port didn't because both instances selected the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### (1) Deploy 2 WARs in a web container

You could build both spring boot projects as WARs and deploy them in the same web container.
Take a look at:

- [How to deploy spring-boot WAR in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233933/641627)
- and [this spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/).

#### (2) Online tutorial on the matter

Otherwise, take a look at this tutorial : http://www.davidtanzer.net/running_multiple_spring_boot_apps_in_the_same_jvm

Comment: Thx. I have seen the tutorial before.

Comment: What about deploying them as wars ?

Comment: Deploy as wars doesn't meet requirement eactly. Because I want to replace the rpc with a direct call between the two app.